# Jquery flot threshold with multiple series

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm trying to create flot line chart with two series on one chart and with threshold option.
I know how to enable threshold when i have only 1 serie (like here http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/thresholding.html ).

Problem is that i cannot do that with more than one serie. My code :

```
   var options = {
                grid: {
                    hoverable: true,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                },
                yaxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100
                },
                xaxis: {
                    mode: "time",
                    timeformat: "%y-%m-%d",
                },
                colors: ["rgb(44,55,66)","rgb(90,2,100)"]

            };
            $.plot($('#chart' + i),[lang,reg], options);
```

lang and reg are my series. I tried to put threshold option inside `options`
 like `threshold: { below: 90, color: "rgb(200, 20, 30)" }`.. but it didn't work, moreover i would like to set more that one color in thresholds so it will be multiple series with multiple colors-levels. 
Do you know how to solve that? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is change your series from arrays to objects.

Right now, you have your data like this:

```
[lang,reg]
```

What you need is:

```
[{
  data:lang,
  threshold: ...
}],
[{
  data:reg,
  threshold: ...
}]
```

You can see an example of how it looks here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/WXrJX/